# how to construct query that joing two tables from Model in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have two tables 'country' and 'destination'. And i want to write a query which goes like this from Destination Model

```
select destination.*, country.name from destination inner join country on destination.country_id = country.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->select('destination.*', 'country.name')->from->('destination')->joinInner('country', '`destination`.`country_id` = `country`.`id`')->setIntegrityCheck(false)->query();
```